# Can noopener and noreferrer attributes be used with the target attribute?

Tags: html

```
<a href="http:www.yahoo.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="tab_a" />link</a>
<a href="http:www.google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="tab_a" />link</a>
```

When I have the rel attributes set, the target attribute is ignored and the links are always opened in a new window.  is there a way to prevent this behavior? and have it ope in the targeted window?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my testing and experience, the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` will disable the feature of opening a link in specific target window.

I was looking for the same functionality but could not achieve it without having to remove the `rel`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need `rel="noopener noreferrer"` attributes because present browsers doesn't consider `noreferrer`. 
Secondly Yes, I was using both with `target="_blank"` attribute with WP plugin External links. That was working for me, you can see this 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQBj6.png).

Comment: Jason is probably trying to fix `target="_blank"` vulnerability issue, see https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/. Also `noreferrer` is needed for Firefox as Firefox does not support `noopener`.